# A couple simple XSLT changes

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT so I believe that what I'm looking for is very basic.

I'm starting with some XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <record>
    <id>10</id>
    <version>v1</version>
    <data>A Value</data>
  </record>
  <record>
    <id>12</id>
    <version>v2</version>
    <data>Another Value</data>
  </record>
</root>
```

I want to do 3 things with this:

- Filter so that I only see v2 results
- Empty out the `<id>`
- Replace "v2" with "v3"

So the result should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <record>
    <id></id>
    <version>v3</version>
    <data>Another Value</data>
  </record>
</root>
```

The original XML is 9MB but this gives the idea.

I've figured out the filtering part, but I'm not sure how to apply multiple templates to the same data at the same time, how to zero out the ID, and how to put a new value in `<version>`.  The new version value is just a static value so it's very straight forward.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 

xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="record">
     <xsl:if test="version='v2'">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
     </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This template will produce the required result from your input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="record[version = 'v2']" />
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="record">
     <record>
       <id></id>
       <version>v3</version>
       <data><xsl:value-of select="data" /></data>
     </record>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`xsl:copy-of` is not suitable for the kind of transformation you want. (tested in [this](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm) web utility).

Comment: Wow, that was fast.  And that's nearly perfect.  Is there any way to remove the line breaks that are generated from the <xsl:value-of>?

Comment: @Scott-Forsyth: which line breakes?

Comment: The XML generated has the format of <data>\nValue\n</data> (\n = new line) rather than just <data>Value</data>.  Is that a property of the output, or something with xsl:value-of?

Comment: Which processor are you using? If the source has not new lines, the output should not as well. Anyway, you can try with normalize-space (as shown in my answer).

Comment: I'm using the web tool that Oded recommended.  I just checked with another tool and it does the opposite and doesn't put any whitespace in (even between elements), so that answers my question anyway, that it's related to the processor.  Thanks!

Comment: @Scott-Forsyth: If you are going to use XSLT seriously, I really suggest using a compliant XSLT processor like Saxon.

Comment: empo, Saxon-HE happens to be the tool that I was using originally.  Good to know that it's the standard to use.

Comment: How are you viewing the output? If you're using a browser or an XML editor, it might be the browser or editor that's adding the whitespace for legibility. The XSLT processor won't add it. It may add whitespace if you specify indent="yes", but even then, it won't add it where you describe it as appearing.

Comment: @Michael - He is using the following web site (which does indeed add the whitespace): http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm

Answer (score 1):

> **Is there any way to remove the line breaks that are generated from the `<xsl:value-of>`?**

Use:

```
<data><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(data)" /></data>
```

Comment: That will remove (some) whitespace from the source document, but so far there is no evidence that the whitespace comes from the source document. So you're guessing. Your guess might be right, but it's a guess all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `xsl:copy-of` you want an identity transformation with templates that change the results:

```
<!-- Process only v2 records -->
<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="record[version = 'v2']"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Change version -->
<xsl:template match="version">
  <xsl:copy>v3</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Remove ID contents -->
<xsl:template match="id">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Identity transformation -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```